# Passing a child of std::ostream to a library that wants std::ostream *

Tags: c++, logging, polymorphism, ostream

I have a class (for logging) which derives from std::ostream. Stripped down, it looks like this:

```
class bsgs : public std::ostream {
public:

  bsgs(const std::string& msg = "") {
    // some setup work
  }

  ~bsgs() {
    // some cleanup work
  }

  template<typename T>
  bsgs& operator<<(const T& rhs) {
    os << rhs;
    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::ostringstream os;
};
```

I wrote this class to do a few particular things I need like delta compression. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I need to pass it to a third-party library (with source, but fairly
large and messy) that provides a "set_out" function to direct its output to a std::ostream. The
set_out function prototype is exactly this:

```
void set_out(std::ostream *out=0, int level=1);
```

and if I call it as:

```
set_out(&std::cout, 3);
```

or

```
set_out(&std::cerr, 5);
```

I get exactly the expected behavior. However, if I write:

```
bsgs logger;
set_out(&logger, 3);
```

I can see that the logger's constructor and destructor are called as expected but `operator<<` is never called. I'm not sure why, and I hope this is a simple question. If I can resolve this problem, I'm all set.

Does anyone know what exactly is going on? The problem seems to be that the library has no clue that I'm passing a pointer to a `bsgs` and not a `std::ostream`, but fixing the library to accept a wider range of objects than just `std::ostream *` looks like it might involve touching 500+ lines of code, which I'd like to avoid.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Edit #1: I'm not sure if it is important, but the library has a virtual `set_out() = 0;` function at the top of its class hierarchy, which is implemented (identically, as far as I can see) in different subclasses. If *I* were writing the library I would have made `set_out` a (non-virtual) template function and provided with a specialization for std::ostream, but let users provide whatever they like so long as they define a usable `operator<<`. Making this change to the library looks like it will be a solid half a day of editing. Maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library **has** no clue that you're passing a pointer to a `bsgs` - you're not overriding a virtual function, there's no polymorphism involved.

You may find that implementing a `streambuf` and replacing a streams associated stream buffer (`ostream::rdbuf`) is a more viable solution.

Comment: I've just made an edit to explain the polymorphism tag, but it isn't important. What _does_ sound important is the streambuf idea: but can you say a bit more about how that works? I know very little about iostreams as you can see, but I would guess that a streambuf is something like a FIFO, and that by implementing my own, I could do whatever I need to get my logging done. Is that right? Off to look up streambuf documentation I guess..!

Comment: A `streambuf` is the backing IO mechanism for a stream - it can read/write characters or sequences of characters, and is called by the stream to do actual IO after the various `operator<<`'s are done with their formatting task

Comment: Thanks. Being lazy, I found boost::iostreams and managed to define a streambuf and get my logger running in just 12 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use

```
std::ostringstream os;
set_out(&os, 3);
```

When you want to derive from ostream, just create your own implementation of [streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/), which is virtual, and create stream like

```
std::ostream stream(new myStreamBuf);
set_out(&stream, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd accept it if I could. What a relief the ostream designers thought to put that in.